# How to condense a dataframe substituting every three columns with just one with the mean value?

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a dataframe that looks like this: (subset)

```
                        Peptide        CNB      CNB.1      CNB.2         UV       UV.1
1          MSRT_RGDSPASSP[K]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
2                MSRT_GLV[K]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
3           MSRT_LGGNETQV[R] -30.156959 -30.156959 -29.764678 -27.362252 -27.063526
4            MSRT_AEFAEVS[K] -11.327429 -11.327429 -11.327429  -9.652082  -9.822783
5          MSRT_SGFSSVSVS[R]   2.402437   2.402437   2.794719   3.150450   2.937075
6            MSRT_ADEGISF[R]   9.071230   8.678948   9.071230   9.423691   9.338341
```

I am new to R. Is there a function I can use to "condense" the data frame to have one column with the mean value of every three consecutive columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335071/condense-a-matrix-in-r

Comment: Do you want the mean of, for example, columns one to three, then four to six, and so on, or do you want a rolling mean of one to three, then two to four , then three to five and so on?

Comment: Im sorry, I want the mean of col one to three, then the mean of col four to six and so on

Comment: Do the linked question/answers answer your question?

Comment: It looks useful, I am trying

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834127/averaging-column-values-of-a-matrix-in-r/26834873#26834873.